# Disable order confirmation email for Bank Wire module only (Prestashop 1.7.6)

Tags: php, prestashop

When a customer orders with "Bank Wire" module, he receives 2 emails, "Order confirmation & Awaiting payment by bank transfer"

so i want to disable the "Order confirmation" email for bank wire only.

Please note that this email shall be sent with other payment methods.

the method in below link remove this email entirety from all payment modules. so if anyone know {IF} statement to be wrote here so that when its "bank wire" method the email shall not sent.

http://www.module-addon.com/2019/02/disable-order-confirmation-email-in.html

Thanks in advance

Comment: inform your error log

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Just edit the
**/classes/paymentModule.php** like this :

```
if ($order->module != "ps_wirepayment") {
     .... Code with the Mail::send() event ....
}
```